# Finding points from one point with certain angle and certain distance python

Tags: python, distance, angle, points

I want to find red points count below picture. Using python. How can I do that?  Using given angle, and distance according to placemark..

Every point has coordinate(latitude,longitude). Placemark also has coordinate.

Fro example, You can use angle 85 degress and its beamwitdh can be taken 50 degress.

there are many red dots in given area. I have some limitations (angle and distance). How can I count red dots?

BR,

[image]

Comment: Please let us know what you have tried already and where you are stuck. Please also provide more elements : what is the distribution of the points, is the dotted line an ellipse ? What is its equation ?

Comment: I can see that there are many red dots. What are the variables of your problem ? Why do you need python ? Please read through this article carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and make your question clearer.

Comment: Have you read through the article ? Don't put the details in the comments, but in the question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is relatively vague so for the time being I am going to assume that this is a circle.

Well, using some math, we can figure out how to get the distance, d, and angle, theta, coordinates based off of the x and y coordinates.

We know:

`x^2 + y^2 = d^2`

`tan(theta) = y/x`

For the actual math behind this, you can draw a right triangle with angle theta, hypotenuse length d, horizontal length x, and vertical length y.

Solving for `theta` and `d`:

`d = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)`

`theta = arctan(y/x)`

Our algorithm will be taking in a list of tuples (to represent points), and seeing if the angle each point makes is within a certain range. Additionally, we will check if the distance each point makes is less than our limit. If both of these conditions are met, then we will increase our total.

Now that we know how to find our coordinates based on the distance and angle, we can easily make our function:

```
import math

def countPoints(maxDist, angle1, angle2, points):
  tot = 0
  for (x,y) in points:
    theta = math.atan(y/x)
    dist = math.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
    if theta > angle1 and theta < angle2:
      if dist < maxDist:
        tot += 1
  return tot
```

Sample:

```
points = [(1,1),(2,3),(3,5),(4,6)]
print(countPoints(4,0,1.2,points))
```

Output:

```
2
```

The first two points have an angle within 0 and 1.2 radians and a distance less than 4.

Note: For this function, we are assuming `angle1 < angle2`, and that if `angle1` dips below the horizontal axis, it will be negative. If your input has `angle1` as positive, but is below the horizontal axis, just multiply it by `-1` before inputting it into the function.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you need any further help or clarification!

Comment: If the distance is greater than the limit distance, it will be outside for any angle. So you could do better and calculate the distance (radius) first, and then if dist < maxDist, calculate and test the angle.

Comment: Wait for your first point I don't get why filtering by distance first makes a difference? There can be points that are out of angle but not out of distance right?

Comment: @LittlePanic404 r u alive/awake enough tho to verify that my answer is right T_T im too lazy to make a better test case and i j wanna double check my algo makes sense

Comment: mh you're right it change nothing. I'm a bit tired. I though about it because the radius for any angle make a closed surface while the angle for any radius make a inf surface (on an infinite space)

Comment: i am too tired to math rn  gn

Comment: It's only drawing! Doing math would be to use determinant instead of trigo to change from the (x,y) base to the new (u,v) base :) gn

Comment: i have not taken linear algebra but (x,y) to (u,v) gives me ptsd about calc 3 change of variables also i am awful at drawing/visualizing :D